# Removing duplicated comments from mysql wordpress database using php code

Tags: php, mysql

I have wordpress blog and I have massive comments under some posts. I found recently that some comments are duplicated two or three times. I want to use php code that removes duplicate elements from table wp_comments from mysql database of Wordpress (by opening php file from server). I used this code, but it doesn't work. Any ideas why? When I run this file I have blank page (no errors, but duplicated comments still there).

Code:

```
<?php

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb;

$comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments"
   ." ORDER BY comment_post_ID, comment_content");

$prev = NULL;

foreach($comments as $comment) {

  if ($prev && $prev->comment_content == $comment->comment_content
    && $prev->comment_post_ID == $comment->comment_post_ID ) {

  echo 'It works';
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments WHERE comment_ID == ".$comment->comment_ID);

  }
  else
    $prev = $comment;
}

$wpdb->print_error();

?>
```

*Maybe you have better idea for this code?*

Comment: Please show some example data from `wp_comments`.

Comment: I'd recommend putting queries outside of the loop.

Comment: Some example data from wp_comments: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17891167/prog.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just spent time formatting your code so I could read it. There is no `{` after your `else`. I believe it is required if you include it in the first part of the if statement. In any case, omitting them in one application but using them in another in the same code block no less, is a terrible practice. Makes your code hard to read/maintain.

Additionally, you may not see an error if errors are suppressed.

Maybe I need to brush up on my PHP but will `if ($prev)` ever be true? It's not a boolean ever is it? It's not like a while when fetching a query. Maybe it is.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following on top of your script, after the opening php tag

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');
```

Run it and tell us everything you see.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in...public_html/test3.php on line 31

Comment: That could be related to not having the opening and closing brackets on the else as Leeish said. Put the open and close brackets and see if that parse error goes away.

Comment: What do you see output on the screen? If you see 'It Works', then the if statement is finding the duplicates but the delete query is probably not working. If you are still just seeing a blank screen, then the if statement is not finding duplicates at all, which means you need to focus on that.

Comment: I'm curious to know if you are actually getting comment rows into $comments. If you put   print_r($comments);   right after that first database query you should be able to see all the comment rows in the $comments array. (assuming that first database query is working)